# Deploy Selected Classes with Ant

Tags: deployment

Supposing you want to deploy only selected classes *using ant* from the force.com ide to various orgs. This can be tricky because you need to ensure both your package.xml and your payload (either your classes directory or a zipfile) contain exactly the same files.

Is there a neat way to do this by defining set ant targets with wildcards for the files to be included?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to ensure your `package.xml` contains at least what you are deploying. It may contain more, but not less.

```
<types>
    <members>Class1</members>
    <members>Class2</members>
    <members>Class3</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
```

UPDATE: It is even easier to do this:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
```

Next, setup an ant target in your `build.xml` which looks something like this:

```
<target name="QADeployClass1And2">
    <delete file="deploy.zip"/>
    <zip destfile="deploy.zip">
        <fileset dir="src" includes="classes/Class1.*"/>
        <fileset dir="src" includes="classes/Class2.*"/>
        <fileset dir="src" includes="package.xml"/>
    </zip>
    <sf:deploy zipFile="deploy.zip" allowMissingFiles="true"
        username="user@org.com.qa" password="**********" 
        serverurl="https://test.salesforce.com"/>
    <delete file="deploy.zip"/>
</target>
```

When you run this target you will deploy only Class1.cls and Class2.cls. I also find it useful to place the `username`, `password` and `serverurl` on the target so that I can use a different ant target for each target org without having to switch out the `build.properties` file.

I use the `zipfile` approach ([1](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html)) because this allows me to easily and centrally control which files go into the payload. If you wish to use a folder with `deployRoot` you need to make a temporary folder and copy in the files you need:

```
<target name="deploy1">
    <delete>
        <fileset dir=".\deploy\classes" includes="**/*.*"/>
    </delete>
    <copy file="deploy\package1.xml" tofile="deploy\package.xml"/>
    <copy todir=".\deploy\classes">
        <fileset dir=".\src\classes\" includes="Class1.*"/>
        <fileset dir=".\src\classes\" includes="Class2.*"/>
    </copy>
    <sf:deploy allowMissingFiles="true" username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" deployRoot="deploy"/>
</target>
```

In this example you could setup `package1.xml` to only include the files you want to deploy and it will overwrite `package.xml` when you run this ant target thus making `allowMissingFiles="true"` superfluous.