# Deploy Salesforce components using Ant and a manifest

Tags: ant

My question here is based on this:

[Deploy Selected Classes with Ant](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7741/deploy-selected-classes-with-ant/7742)

But since that question has seven years, is there a better way to deploy metadata components with Ant using a manifest.xml to declare which components you want to deploy to an Org?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Salesforce DX supports [manifest-based development](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_any_org.htm) against any org, using the `force:source:deploy` command. You can use a `package.xml` or specify exactly which metadata components you wish to deploy on the command line, e.g.,

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -m "ApexClass, Profile:Content Experience Profile"
```

to deploy all Apex classes and one specific Profile. (More examples are in the linked documentation).

While you *can* still use Ant, Salesforce DX is likely a better solution - it's more modern, better at using OAuth (or JWT) authentication, and offers additional tools around deployment as well.

Comment: +1 Also, don't forget about `force:source:deploy -p path-to-file` which can use wildcards to deploy selectively directly from the terminal.

Comment: Thank you David, I think I'll  go for DX, I just wanted to avoid rewriting the whole CI environment already done in Jenkins

Comment: And for an actual `manifest.xml` file you can use `force:source:deploy -x ./manifest/package.xml -u MyDestinationOrg`